# Is there a way to track progress towards the badges

Tags: discussion, badges

For example, is there a way to know how close to the editor badge you are?

Comment: Seems you couldn't be far off!

Comment: @Pat I'm an awful tinkerer with tags.

Comment: @Jeremiah - I think thats awesome.  We definitely need editors and archivists here.  I think those positions are as valuable as quality questions/answers (you do those too)

Comment: @Jeremiah - So that's why you've been editing every post you could get your hand on since you broke 1K.  Not cool.

Comment: @Iszi No, I edit because I'm a complusive organizer. Tags intrinsically hit all my hot buttons and I'm continually poking and prodding them. But even so, editing is part of stackexchange. As a group we probably don't spend enough time editing (if you look at the original stackexchanegs the amount of edits is phenomenally high)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is only looking at the [Copy Editor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/badges/33/copy-editor) / [Strunk & White](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) badges:

---

The short answer is **no**, as far as I can tell after searching [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

The medium answer is to check out these posts on meta that don't really answer your question:

- [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/150909)
- [What are the requirements for the Copy Editor badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66586/150909)

The long answer is also **no**.

For sites in the Stack Exchange network that have graduated, there is **[SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/)** (the Stack Exchange Data Explorer). That lets users create queries that can be run against the data and [this one](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/5117) will get approximate progress on the editor badge for the StackOverflow.com site given a user ID number. But RPG.se is not included in that data yet.

If RPG.se is included in the big (monthly?) [data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19579/150909), you could download that and try to query it yourself... :)